# what is the correct way to use sys.getsizeof to get the size of a database in python?

Tags: python, sys

I have a large leveldb database named, db.

```
tot=0
i=0
for key,value in db.RangeIter():
    tot=sys.getsizeof(key)+sys.getsizeof(value)
    i=i+1
print(f'total rows:  {i}')
print(f'total size:  {tot}')
```

gives

```
total rows:  119113
total size:  143
```

which is really odd.

So I wrote this:

```
keyTot=0
valTot=0
for key,value in db.RangeIter():
    keyTot += len(key)
    valTot += len(value)

print(f'Total key size:  {keyTot}  Total value size:    {valTot}    Total:  {keyTot+valTot}')
```

which gave

```
Total key size:  1404729  Total value size:    452897532    Total:  454302261
```

So what was sys.getsizeof measuring when I passed it the key? And how did it come up with such a small number after iterating through 119113 rows?

Comment: Be aware that due to extensive use of references in Python the returned size of many types does fully reflect the real size in memory.

Comment: This is probably not going to give you a useful number even after you use the fix in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Do you imagine this is keeping a **running** total?

```
tot=sys.getsizeof(key)+sys.getsizeof(value)
```

It is **not**, you are overwriting `tot` on every iteration

Comment: now works properlytotal rows:  119113
total size:  467881143